# How to add element along with its attributes using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Using XDocument i can add an element by

```
new XElement("elementName", "elementText");
```

and add an attribute by

```
new XAttribute("attributeName", "attributeValue");
```

However when i use the following code

```
XDocument doc =
  new XDocument(
      new XElement("Address", new XAttribute("name", "sample"))
  );
```

there is no text being added for the element 'Address' 
How to add both element and attribute at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `string` as another `XElement` constructor parameter, and it will be placed as element content:

```
XDocument doc =
    new XDocument(
        new XElement("Address",
            new XAttribute("name", "sample"),
            "elementText"
        )
    );
```

Calling `doc.ToString()` now gives `<Address name="sample">elementText</Address>`.

Just to let you know: it can be done with `XText` class too, but I think using plain `string` is more convenient:

```
XDocument doc =
    new XDocument(
        new XElement("Address",
            new XAttribute("name", "sample"),
            new XText("elementText")
        )
    );
```